# Box Requireent for Flush Mount Light on Plywood Ceiling

Tags: electrical, lighting, ceiling

I am replacing a fixture in our kitchen. I removed the old fixture, and low-and-behold, the ceiling is solid plywood in this area - and there is no box. Should one be added, or does having solid wood there negate the need for it? The wires are coming out of a roughly 3/4" hole in the wood

If a box is required, is a standard old work box ok? Can I mount a pancake box to the surface?

This is an LED surface mount light, no fan. Weighs maybe a pound

Comment: In North America, a junction box is require for making connections, so will need a box for the light that fits and someone is getting on Santa's naughty list.

Comment: @crip659 - doesn't the light fixture itself count as a 'box', assuming it has terminals for each of the wires?

Comment: @Tetsujin  Think it counts as the cover for the box.  Point being to prevent stuff(fingers) from touching live wires, and to have separation from stuff that can burn, like plywood.

Comment: @crip659 - ah, OK. I'm too used to the UK system, where the ceiling 'rose' is actually the circuit junction box as well.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/fz3b0.png then the lighting pendant completes the 'box'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pancake box will be ok, but possibly not allow a fixture to be installed flush to the ceiling. The old works box is your best bet. They can be found round and in different depths.